# Should no-arg constructor initialize fields in the context of jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb

Suppose we have this class for jaxb to serialize:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Property {
    private String key;
    private Object value;

    public Property(String key, Object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Property() {
        // a no-arg default constructor is needed; 
        // otherwise, a "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException" is thrown
    }
}
```

The question is for the no-arg constructor `Property()` :

Do we need to initialize the fields (`key` and `value`)? If so, what should they be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JAXB implementation does not require that you initialize the fields.  This would depend upon your use case.

### Mapping to Fields

If you do not provider accessor methods for your fields then you should specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class, so that JAXB will treat those fields as mapped.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

### Constructor

You could add a private constructor.  This would meet JAXB's requirements and restrict access to it.

### Immutable Fields

If the fields in your object was immutable then you could create an `XmlAdapter` for your class to handle this use case.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html